# Setting the User UID in a Bitnami Docker Container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, bitnami

I am running a number of [Bitnami Docker containers](https://github.com/bitnami) which all uses a user UID of `1001` inside the container. However, these containers needs to write files to a mounted host directory as a user with UID `1010`.

Is there a way to achieve this, apart from rewriting all the Dockerfiles involved and rebuilding all these images?

Using Docker Compose 1.25.5 and Docker 19.03.8 on Ubuntu 20.04. The user `1001` in the container also happens to have no name:

```
I have no name!@32f6e5ad9cbd:/$ id
uid=1001 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

I have no name!@32f6e5ad9cbd:/$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1001
```

```
$ cat /etc/passwd

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:100:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Have you tried `user: 1010:1010` in your compose file?

Comment: @hmm Yes but permissions occur, probably when user `1010` tries to read/write files that still belong to user `1001`. These files were probably created when the Docker image was built?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `user: 1010:0`.

If you use the `root` (`0`) for the GID you shouldn't have issues with permissions:

```
$ id
uid=1010 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, but this worked for me. Thanks